# Is it possible to specify the strategy option, for pulls (--rebase) on a (local) repository?

Tags: git, rebase, pull, merge-conflict-resolution

I use a program that is stored as github reposity on the user (my) machine; it updates itself periodically, by just pulling (with rebase) the remote repository.

I made a change that creates conflicts frequently.

Since I don't have control on how the program executes the pull (barring create a fork, and either change the pull code, or manually pull from upstream), I was wondering if I can configure the (local) repository, so that `pull --rebase` executes with the `strategy-option`of my choice.

Is this possible?

Comment: Other than passing `-s` through `git pull`, no.

Comment: The easiest way is to split your `git pull` command in two : run `git fetch`, followed by `git rebase <options> origin/thatbranch` or `git rebase <options> @{u}` (`@{u}` is short for "the upstream branch of current branch")